# SQL Server instalation on Win 7

Tags: sql-server-2005, installation

I instaled SQL Server 2005 64bit extended on Win 7 64bit and I can't start mssqlservice. it isn't listed amoung services. when i try to connect on the database with the SQL Management studio in the "server name" select box i don't have any instances.

I tried UAC disabling and that didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

SQL Server 2005 SP3 and SQL Server 2008 SP1 is the only versions supported on Windows 7. It should have given a warning during installation however if the correct SP is not already applied.

The service itself is now called SQL Server and not MSSQLServer. If you are running an instance it will be called SQL Server (INSTANCE NAME)

Comment: Windows Update isn't showing me that i have to install it. Very strange.

Comment: I have instaled "Service Pack 3 for SQL Server Tools and Workstation Components 2005" which obviously isn't enough.

Comment: No, dl it manually. http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=ae7387c3-348c-4faa-8ae5-949fdfbe59c4&displaylang=en